# How to save persistent data structure into elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a relational DB, and it saved a persistent segment tree structure, means all parent and children are always manyToMany, the height of this tree is about 4 to 5 levels

Persistent segment tree reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/persistent-segment-tree-set-1-introduction/

Because it is segment tree, node data won't change much, when it changed, there should be another node generated

My questions is which way I should save my data into elastic search.

My current thought:

1. nested will build too many documents, anything changes from leaf node will generate a new root, and in new root, will make a lot of redundant data, because a lot of un-versioned nodes are not changed, and it is hard to trace node versioning
2. parent-child mode looks good fit, however each node may have multiple parents and children,
   this many-to-many relationship is almost everywhere from my DB, denormalize it seems impossible, the solution that I could think of is maintaining children and parents IDs from each level, but it makes so hard to maintain, plus join might make it slow

**Please enlight me with your ideas.**